# RandomizedSearchCV taking too long on Random Forest

Tags: python, bigdata, random-forest, grid-search, hyperparameters

I'm trying to do classification for a churn analysis with big data. RandomizedSearchCV method is running for at least 6 hours and I need to find a way to decrease the time of it.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 200, stop = 2000, num = 10)]

max_features = ['auto', 'sqrt']

max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(100, 500, num = 11)]
max_depth.append(None)

random_grid = {
 'n_estimators': n_estimators,
 'max_features': max_features,
 'max_depth': max_depth
 }
rfc_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rfc, param_distributions = random_grid, n_iter = 100, cv = 3, verbose=2, random_state=42, n_jobs = -1)
rfc_random.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(rfc_random.best_params_)
```

Comment: use faster server on internet. ie. [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)

Comment: It didn't work on google colab too

Comment: if it don't work faster on faster computer then you will have to wait 6 hours. And maybe you should save model after training and later load it so you don't have train it again.

Comment: shorter code to get integers `n_estimators = np.linspace(..., dtype=int)` eventually `n_estimators = np.linspace(...).astype(int)`